# Only static members can be accessed in initializer

Tags: flutter, dart

i can not use the `GlobalKey` in `Scaffold`. The error is

> Only static members can be accessed in initializer

```
//Global key
  final GlobalKey<ScaffoldState> _mainKey= GlobalKey<ScaffoldState>();
// List of TabBar
final List<Widget> tabBar = <Widget>[
    Column(
      children: <Widget>[
        Icon(Icons.account_balance_wallet),
        Text('flutter'),
        Text('dart')
      ],
    ),
    FlatButton(
      child: Text('Open Drawer'),
      onPressed: (){
         //( _mainKey) has a red underLine color
        _mainKey.currentState.openDrawer();
      },
    )
  ];
/*
Compiler message:
lib/Trial.dart:32:9: Error: Can't access 'this' in a field initializer to read '_mainKey'.
        _mainKey.currentState.openDrawer();*/
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Short answer**

Replace

```
final _mainKey = ...;
```

with

```
static _mainKey = ...;
```

---

**Long answer:**

I would suggest you to change your `tabBar` from variable to method, this way you don't need to make your variable `static`. Like:

```
List<Widget> getTabBar() {
  return [
    Column(
      children: <Widget>[Icon(Icons.account_balance_wallet), Text('flutter'), Text('dart')],
    ),
    FlatButton(
      child: Text('Open Drawer'),
      onPressed: () {
        _mainKey.currentState.openDrawer();
      },
    )
  ];
}
```

Comment: could you tell me the reason why,please?

Comment: Because you can't use non-static member in initializer list, I have updated the question to provide you a better solution.

Comment: Thank You soOoOo Much ,i understood both the short and long answer,Thanks

Comment: Hey what happened you earlier accepted the answer and you just undo that? May I know what didn't work in this solution

Comment: yeah,i dont konw why!
i did it again